# if combo box is array value then populate alternative combo box VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, combobox

I have 2 combo boxes on my userform if combo box 1 states 'Germany Home Shopping' if gives the following array

```
If ComboBox1.Value = "Germany Home Shopping" Then
ComboBox2.List = Array("GER Singles ABE", "GER Singles CDF", "GER Small Cat ABE", "GER Small Cat CDF", "GER Small Cat All Zone", "GER Large Cat ABE", "GER Large Cat CDF", "GER Large Cat All Zone")
End If
```

I also want to do it the opposite where if the value is one of the array answers in combobox 2 then it will put Germany Home Shopping in Combo Box 1. I thought this could be done like this?

```
If ComboBox2.List = Array("GER Singles ABE", "GER Singles CDF", "GER Small Cat ABE", "GER Small Cat CDF", "GER Small Cat All Zone", "GER Large Cat ABE", "GER Large Cat CDF", "GER Large Cat All Zone") Then
ComboBox1.Value = "Germany Home Shopping" 
End If
```

But this doesn't seem to be working for me.

Thanks in advance :-)
Al

Comment: change your if statement to loop through the array testing like `for each ele in Array(x, y ,z): if combobox2.selecteditem = ele then: combobox1.value = "Germany etc..": exit for: end if: Next`

Comment: @Cor_Blimey I'm getting a compile error stating method or data member not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim mylist
mylist = Array("GER Singles ABE", "GER Singles CDF", "GER Small Cat ABE", _
         "GER Small Cat CDF", "GER Small Cat All Zone", "GER Large Cat ABE", _
         "GER Large Cat CDF", "GER Large Cat All Zone") 
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Me.ComboBox2.Value, mylist, 0)) Then
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Germany Home Shopping"
End If
```

Comment: This does update the combobox1 to the relevant channel however it then turns the combobox2 back to blank.

Comment: @AlanTreanor Actually I was wondering why you would want to do this. It doesn't add up specially if you have a *Change_Event* in **ComboBox1** to populate **ComboBox2** List. So basically it's either **ComboBox2** list is based on **ComboBox1** or vise-versa.